# Can CSS3 enabled elements make a position transition?

Tags: google-chrome, css, css-transitions

I was just playing around with my portfolio site and noticed that when my (Google Chrome) screen was zoomed in to 400% and focused on the footer, I have some elements that don't match the fluid grid. I know I need to find a fix for this (if you have any ideas / advice on how to position elements for a fantasticly fluid layout, please post them), but when I used the hotkey for 'View as Actual Size', I noticed that an element that I had two separate CSS3 transition-enabled parameters (opacity and width, code located below) applied to it does a smooth, slow transition from the original placement to the place it holds in the 'Actual Size' view.

http://jsfiddle.net/Asustaba/VLw7k/

Apologies if this is confusing. I can attach a link for a video of the transition if anybody needs a better idea of what is happening.

```
.grower{
  -moz-transform: scale(.85);
  -webkit-transform: scale(.85);
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.grower:hover{
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1); 
}

.grower_big{
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.grower_big:hover{
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1); 
}
```

Has anybody run into this yet? Is it possible to set a transition based movement (ease-in-out) between absolute, relative, or normal-flow positioning of elements? What about when viewed within a parallax-based web layout?

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle with the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking if you can transition the property position. If this is the case then you cannot. Most elements that can be transitioned are ones that use a numerical value. Here is a list of CSS properties that can be transitioned: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#properties-from-css-